# Trigger's with identation cursor[Edit]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good morning people,

This is my first post here, I've been working over a database for an APP for my job and I need a few clues over a trigger I've got that's turning me mad.

EDIT:

Given the next structure:

Users Table:

```
[dbo].[ENGIE_Users]
(
[dbID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Nombre] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[Apellidos] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
[HashContraseña] [binary](64) NOT NULL,
[Email] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Direccion] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
[Codigo Postal] [nvarchar](5) NOT NULL,
[Telefono] [nvarchar](12) NOT NULL,
[Venta a Nº Cliente] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[POS Asignado] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[User_Number]  AS ([dbo].[EngieUsers]([dbID])),
[Salt] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
```

Constraints:
dbID Primary Key
Email No-Pk Unique

Here it's where we store the users from the APP.

User-Material table:

```
[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material]
(
[ID User] [int] NOT NULL,
[EAN] [nvarchar](13) NOT NULL,
[Product Number] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Venta] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Cantidad Actual] [int] NOT NULL,
[Cantidad Total] [int] NOT NULL,
[Descripcion Corta] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[PVP Neto] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
[% DTO] [decimal](38, 20) NOT NULL,
```

Primary Key ID User + Product Number + EAN
ID user references the dbID from Users.

This table is used to store the quantities of the products each user has asigned to his "account".

Orders table:

```
[dbo].[ENGIE_Ended_Orders]
(
[dbID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ID User] [int] NOT NULL,
[Procesado] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Finalizado] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Fecha de realizacion] [date] NOT NULL,
[OT] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Order Id]  AS ([dbo].[EngiePedidos]([dbID])),
[Total Pedido] [decimal](38, 20) NULL,
```

Primary key dbID

ID User foreign key references dbId from users
This table will contain the "Head" of the order.

Order-Content Table

```
[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content]    
(
[Order Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[Product Number] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,
[Procesado] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Finalizado] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[Fecha de realizacion] [date] NOT NULL,
[Cantidad] [int] NOT NULL,
[ID Pedido] [nchar](8) NULL,
```

Primary key Product Number + Order Id
Foreign key Order Id references Orders dbID

So, given this structure what I need is the next restrictions:

On User-Material :
It's own Actual Quantity never has to overcome the Total Quantity. (Inserts/Updates)

On Order-Content:
When an order is inserted or updated, it has to fulfill the restriction above (So if you ask 5, you must have 5 units avaliable of this product for you to buy)
Also, when it's inserted/updated/deleted the trigger has to calculate the "Order Total" as for a formula that's (quantity * (price - (price*100/discount))).

On Orders:
So there's 2 tables more (Same structure as Orders/Order-Content, called Ended Orders/Ended Order Con tent) witch this table will transfer all the rows of those tables to the other 2 when the boolean [Finalizado] is = 1. And will restore the Actual Quantity associated to the user of those items witch where in this Ended Order.

Work done:

Triggers:
On user-Material

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Qty_Restriction]
ON [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    IF(SELECT [Cantidad Actual] FROM INSERTED) > (SELECT [Cantidad Total] FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('La Cantidad Actual no debe superar la Cantidad Total',18,1);
    END 
    ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ENGIE.dbo.ENGIE_User_Material SELECT [ID User],[EAN],    [Product Number],[Venta],[Cantidad Actual],[Cantidad Total],[Descripcion Corta],    [PVP Neto],[% DTO] FROM INSERTED;
    END
END
```

This won't let you insert regs with more actual quantity than total quantity.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Qty_Restriction_2]

ON [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material]

INSTEAD OF UPDATE

AS

DECLARE @material varchar(13)
DECLARE @pno varchar(20)
DECLARE @usuario int

SET @material = (SELECT [EAN] FROM INSERTED)
SET @pno = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED)
SET @usuario = (SELECT [ID User] FROM INSERTED)  

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    IF UPDATE([Cantidad Actual])
    BEGIN
        IF(SELECT [Cantidad Actual] FROM INSERTED) > (SELECT [Cantidad Total] FROM INSERTED)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('La Cantidad Actual no debe superar la Cantidad Total',18,1);
        END 
        ELSE BEGIN
            UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] SET [Cantidad Actual] = (SELECT [Cantidad Actual] FROM INSERTED) WHERE [Product Number] = @pno AND [EAN] = @material AND [ID User] = @usuario  
        END
    END
    IF UPDATE([Cantidad Total])
    BEGIN
        IF(SELECT [Cantidad Actual] FROM INSERTED) > (SELECT [Cantidad Total] FROM INSERTED)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('La Cantidad Actual no debe superar la Cantidad Total',18,1);
        END 
        ELSE BEGIN
            UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] SET [Cantidad Total] = (SELECT [Cantidad Total] FROM INSERTED) WHERE [Product Number] = @pno AND [EAN] = @material AND [ID User] = @usuario  
        END
    END
    IF UPDATE([Venta])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] SET [Venta] = (SELECT [Venta] FROM INSERTED) WHERE [Product Number] = @pno AND [EAN] = @material AND [ID User] = @usuario  
    END
    IF UPDATE([Descripcion Corta])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] SET [Descripcion Corta] = (SELECT [Descripcion Corta] FROM INSERTED) WHERE [Product Number] = @pno AND [EAN] = @material AND [ID User] = @usuario  
    END
    IF UPDATE([PVP Neto])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] SET [PVP Neto] = (SELECT [PVP Neto] FROM INSERTED) WHERE [Product Number] = @pno AND [EAN] = @material AND [ID User] = @usuario  
    END
    IF UPDATE([% DTO])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] SET [% DTO] = (SELECT [% DTO] FROM INSERTED) WHERE [Product Number] = @pno AND [EAN] = @material AND [ID User] = @usuario  
    END
END
```

This one the same, but with update.

On Orders:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TransferenceOrders_Inner]

   ON  [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders]

   AFTER UPDATE

AS 

DECLARE @material nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @cant int
DECLARE @cantant int
DECLARE @usr int

DECLARE CURSOR_CANTIDAD CURSOR FOR
SELECT [Cantidad],[Product Number],[ID User] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content] A, INSERTED I WHERE A.[Numero_Pedido] = I.Numero_Pedido

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE([Finalizado])
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE A SET [Finalizado] = I.Finalizado FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] A INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON A.dbID = I.dbID;

        INSERT INTO [ENGIE].dbo.[ENGIE_Ended_Orders] ([Numero_Pedido],[ID User],[Fecha de realizacion],[OT],[ID Pedido],[Total Pedido]) 
    (SELECT [dbID],[ID User],[Fecha de realizacion],[OT],[Numero_Pedido],[Total Pedido] FROM INSERTED)

        INSERT INTO [ENGIE].dbo.[ENGIE_Ended_Order_Content] ([Numero_Pedido],[Product Number],[Fecha de realizacion],[Cantidad],[ID Pedido]) 
    (SELECT [Numero_Pedido],[Product Number],[Fecha de realizacion],[Cantidad],[ID Pedido] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content] A INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON A.Numero_Pedido = I.dbID)

        OPEN CURSOR_CANTIDAD
        FETCH CURSOR_CANTIDAD INTO @cant,@material,@usr
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ENGIE.dbo.ENGIE_User_Material SET [Cantidad Actual] = (SELECT [Cantidad Actual] FROM ENGIE.dbo.ENGIE_User_Material A,INSERTED I WHERE A.[Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM ENGIE.dbo.[ENGIE_Order_Content] B,INSERTED C WHERE B.Numero_Pedido = C.dbID)
         AND A.[ID User] = I.[ID User])-@cant WHERE [Product Number] = @material AND [ID User] = @usr)          
            FETCH CURSOR_CANTIDAD INTO @cant,@material,@usr
        END
        CLOSE CURSOR_CANTIDAD; 
        DELETE A FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] A INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON I.[dbID] = A.[dbID] AND A.[ID User] = I.[ID User];
    END
    DEALLOCATE CURSOR_CANTIDAD; 
END
```

This trigger needs the cursor, because it has to replenish the quantities of the content of the order that it just processed.

On Order_Content:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AutoIDOrder_DEL]

ON [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content]

AFTER DELETE

AS

DECLARE @numped int
DECLARE @prod nchar(20)
DECLARE @pvp decimal(38,20)
DECLARE @pvpsdto decimal(38,20)
DECLARE @dto decimal(38,20)
DECLARE @cantidad int

SET @numped = (SELECT Numero_Pedido FROM INSERTED)
SET @prod = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED)
SET @cantidad = (SELECT [Cantidad] FROM INSERTED)
SET @pvp = (SELECT [Total Pedido] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] WHERE [dbID] = @numped)

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    SET @pvpsdto = (SELECT [PVP Neto] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [Product Number] = @prod)
    SET @dto = (SELECT [% DTO] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [Product Number] = @prod)
    UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] SET [Total Pedido] = @pvp-(@cantidad*((@pvpsdto*100)/@dto)) WHERE [dbID] = @numped
END
```

This one will update "Order Total" from Orders when you're deleting a registry from order content.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Qty_Restriction_3]

ON [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content]

INSTEAD OF INSERT

AS

DECLARE @cantAnt int
DECLARE @cantAct int
DECLARE @cant int
DECLARE @pvpsdto decimal(38,20)
DECLARE @dto decimal(38,20)
DECLARE @total decimal(38,20)

SET @cant = (SELECT [Cantidad] FROM INSERTED)
SET @cantAnt = (SELECT [Cantidad Total] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED) AND [ID User] = (SELECT [ID User] FROM INSERTED))
SET @cantAct = (SELECT [Cantidad Actual] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material]WHERE [Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED) AND [ID User] = (SELECT [ID User] FROM INSERTED))
SET @pvpsdto = (SELECT [PVP Neto] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED) AND [ID User] = (SELECT [ID User] FROM INSERTED))
SET @dto = (SELECT [% DTO] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED) AND [ID User] = (SELECT [ID User] FROM INSERTED))
SET @total = (SELECT [Total Pedido] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] WHERE [dbID] = (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED)) 
IF(@total IS NULL) 
BEGIN
    SET @total = 0.0
END

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    BEGIN
        IF((@cantAct+@cant) > @cantAnt)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('La Cantidad Actual no debe superar la Cantidad Total',18,1);
        END 
        ELSE BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ENGIE.dbo.ENGIE_Order_Content SELECT * FROM INSERTED;
            UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content] SET [ID Pedido] = (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] WHERE [dbID] LIKE (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED)) WHERE [Numero_Pedido] LIKE (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED) AND [Product Number] LIKE (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED);
            UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content] SET [Fecha de realizacion] = (SELECT [Fecha de realizacion] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] WHERE [dbID] =  (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED)) WHERE [Numero_Pedido] LIKE (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED) AND [Product Number] LIKE (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED);
        ----> AUQUI CALCULO DE TOTAL

            UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] SET [Total Pedido] = (@total+(@cant*(@pvpsdto-((@pvpsdto*@dto)/100)))) WHERE [dbID] = (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED)
        END
    END
END
```

This one will avoid to insert a quantity on order content that does not meet the requirements of (Actual Quantity <= Total Quantity) + Will calculate the total of the order in base to the productss you're adding to the order.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Qty_Restriction_4]

ON [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content]

INSTEAD OF UPDATE

AS

DECLARE @cantAnt int
DECLARE @cantAct int
DECLARE @cant int
DECLARE @pvpsdto decimal(38,20)
DECLARE @dto decimal(38,20)
DECLARE @bool bit
DECLARE @total decimal(38,20)

SET @bool = 0;
SET @cant = (SELECT [Cantidad] FROM INSERTED)
SET @userId = (SELECT [ID User] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] WHERE [dbID] = (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED)) 
SET @cantAnt = (SELECT [Cantidad Total] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [ID User] = @userId AND [Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED))
SET @cantAct = (SELECT [Cantidad Actual] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [ID User] = @userId AND [Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED))
SET @pvpsdto = (SELECT [PVP Neto] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED) AND [ID User] = (SELECT [ID User] FROM INSERTED))
SET @dto = (SELECT [% DTO] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_User_Material] WHERE [Product Number] = (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED) AND [ID User] = (SELECT [ID User] FROM INSERTED))
SET @total = (SELECT [Total Pedido] FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] WHERE [dbID] = (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED)) 
IF(@total IS NULL) 
BEGIN
    SET @total = 0.0
END

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    IF UPDATE([Cantidad])
    BEGIN
        IF((@cantAct+@cant) > @cantAnt)
        BEGIN
            RAISERROR('La Cantidad Actual no debe superar la Cantidad Total',18,1);
        --->ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END 
        ELSE BEGIN
            UPDATE ENGIE.dbo.ENGIE_Order_Content SET [Cantidad] = (SELECT [Cantidad] FROM inserted) WHERE [Numero_Pedido]= (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED) AND [Product Number]= (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED)
            SET @bool = 1;
        END;
    END;
    IF UPDATE([Procesado])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ENGIE.dbo.ENGIE_Order_Content SET [Procesado] = (SELECT [Procesado] FROM inserted) WHERE [Numero_Pedido]= (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED) AND [Product Number]= (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED)
    END;
    IF UPDATE([Finalizado])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ENGIE.dbo.ENGIE_Order_Content SET [Finalizado] = (SELECT [Finalizado] FROM inserted) WHERE [Numero_Pedido]= (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED) AND [Product Number]= (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED)
    END;
    IF UPDATE([ID Pedido])
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ENGIE.dbo.ENGIE_Order_Content SET [ID Pedido] = (SELECT [ID Pedido] FROM inserted) WHERE [Numero_Pedido]= (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED) AND [Product Number]= (SELECT [Product Number] FROM INSERTED)
    END;
---> AQUI METER LO DEL AFTER UPDATE, PARA QUE NO HAYA PROBLEMA, CON UN BOOLEAN
    IF (@bool = 1) 
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
        UPDATE [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] SET [Total Pedido] = (@total+(@cant*(@pvpsdto-((@pvpsdto*@dto)/100)))) WHERE [dbID] = (SELECT [Numero_Pedido] FROM INSERTED)
    END;
END
```

This last one pretends to do the same as the insert but on update, making the restriction of actual Qty to work and give value to the [Order Total] column

Comment: write a stored proc

Comment: Are you using `sql-server` or `plsql`? Please remove the irrelevant tag.

Comment: Done, its tsql no plsql.

Comment: @BorisPomarol , for second edit Constraint can't be used for this. I think you need to insert or update the column if [actual quantity]<[total quantity]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trigger doesn't handle multi row insert. What if the

```
SET @usuario = (SELECT [ID User] FROM INSERTED)
```

returns more than one value. it will fail. And a cursor inside a trigger is very bad thing. You should re write your trigger using set based approach
Your first 4 statements should be re written

```
UPDATE A
SET [Finalizado] = i.Finalizado
FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] A
INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON a.dbID = i.dbid;

INSERT INTO [ENGIE].dbo.[ENGIE_Ended_Orders] (
    [Numero_Pedido]
    ,[ID User]
    ,[Fecha de realizacion]
    ,[OT]
    ,[ID Pedido]
    )
SELECT [dbID]
    ,[ID User]
    ,[Fecha de realizacion]
    ,[OT]
    ,[Numero_Pedido]
FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders]
FROM inserted

INSERT INTO [ENGIE].dbo.[ENGIE_Ended_Order_Content] (
    [Numero_Pedido]
    ,[Product Number]
    ,[Fecha de realizacion]
    ,[Cantidad]
    ,[ID Pedido]
    )
SELECT [Numero_Pedido]
    ,[Product Number]
    ,[Fecha de realizacion]
    ,[Cantidad]
    ,[ID Pedido]
FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Order_Content] A
INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON A.Numero_Pedido = I.Dbid

DELETE A
FROM [ENGIE].[dbo].[ENGIE_Orders] A
INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON
WHERE I.[dbID] = A.DBID
    AND A.[ID User] = I.USERID;
```

I am not sure I met your criteria(especillay the joins please do a check on it) but the trigger should be rewritten with set based logic and I hope the cursor can be also be eliminated

Comment: Morning, what if the case I wanted a trigger in the own table wich wouldn't let update the Actual Quantity Unless its lower or equal to Total Quantity, how would I play with the aritmetic operation? Can't use:

INSTEAD OF UPDATE...
AS....
...
IF SELECT [Cantidad Actual] FROM INSERTED > SELECT [Cantidad Total] FROM INSERTED ,
BEGIN
---> RAISE ERROR
END
ELSE BEGIN
-> PERFORM UPDATE
END

How could I bypass this problem?

Comment: @BorisPomarol , can you add a constraint for this on the column?

Comment: The transition of working with C/AL in Dynamics NAV to pure T-SQL is making me suffer at some points, the core is that I do not understand all the expectrum of things I can do with T-SQL.

So yeah, I can put a constraint here. I should put 2 then, one on Actual Quantity and another one on Total Quantity right? And how you'd tell a constraint to restrict another field's value depending on its own? (It's a little confusing).

Thanks,

Comment: @BorisPomarol so you can have only pure tsql no strored procs right? Can you update the question with new requirement. Leave constraints in columns since you requirement is update if a certain quantity is met.

Comment: Pure T-SQL yeah, I've let it eddited in the main question. But if it's via constraint it's really easier for us to approach, we'd be supressing 2 triggers this way

Comment: @BorisPomarol , I am not sure about using the constraint in your case with out knowing the requirement. After the edit I will have a look.